# Attempting to call a specific name to a function

Tags: python

I'm feeling quite generally stupid at the moment.

I've been attempting to get my function to run a some code once a specific name has been inputted.

I feel as if the code I am putting together is quite childish and I'm currently trying to find some help on what I am doing wrong. Any input is appreciated. I apologise for my messy code.

I want to simply get my function argument (cond) to be able to run this specific code if its either inexpensive, large_screen or apple_product. Thanks for all your help :)

def satisfies(product, cond):

```
inexpensive = (4, '<=', 1000)
large_screen = (2, '>=', 6.3)
apple_product = (1, '==', 'Apple')

conditions = (inexpensive, large_screen, apple_product)

if cond == conditions[0]:
    if cond[1] == '<=':
        return True if cond[2] <= product[4] else False
    elif cond[1] == '<=':
        return True if cond[2] <= product[4] else False
    elif cond[1] == '==':
        return True if cond[2] == product[4] else False

if cond == conditions[1]:
    if cond[1] == '<=':
        return True if cond[2] <= product[4] else False
    elif cond[1] == '<=':
        return True if cond[2] <= product[4] else False
    elif cond[1] == '==':
        return True if cond[2] == product[4] else False

if cond == conditions[2]:
    if cond[1] == '==':
        return True if cond[2] == product[1] else False
```

**Input : A product feature list (product() and a condition
            (cond) as specified above.
Output: True if cond holds for the product otherwise False.**

Calling satisfies(['Nova 5T', 'Huawei', 6.26, 3750, 497], inexpensive) should return True.

Comment: Inside first `if` block. You are comparing 0th index of `cond`. Shouldn't it be the first index? Because the operator strings are at the first index of the tuple

Comment: What's `cond` typically? And `product`? :-)  Please give us the whole function definition. Along with a phrase definition of what you'd expect as input/output, that'd help a lot.

Comment: Also, you never check `>=`. You check for `<=` twice in both of the larger if statement blocks.

Comment: `is` is not an equality operator. Do not use it. Use `==`.

Comment: Why are using `if cond is conditions[0]` rather than `if cond == conditions[0]`?  `is` is not used to check if things have the same value.

Comment: @Arnaud In general, not the same.

Comment: @busybear thanks that a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code by

- splitting it into two functions:

  - one that checks a single condition
  - another that checks many using a combinator function; the default is `all()`, for "AND"; if you want, you can use `combinator=any` for an "OR" sort of query).
- using the `operator` module, which contains predicate functions for various operators, and a mapping for your operator strings to those functions

```
import operator

operators = {
    "<=": operator.le,
    ">=": operator.ge,
    "==": operator.eq,
    "!=": operator.ne,
    "<": operator.lt,
    ">": operator.gt,
}


def check_condition(product, cond):
    field, operator, value = cond
    return operators[operator](product[field], value)


def check_conditions(product, conditions, combinator=all):
    return combinator(
        check_condition(product, cond)
        for cond in conditions
    )


def check_products_conditions(products, conditions, combinator=all):
    return [
        product 
        for product in products 
        if check_conditions(product, conditions, combinator=combinator)
    ]


inexpensive = (4, "<=", 1000)
large_screen = (2, ">=", 6.3)
apple_product = (1, "==", "Apple")

product = ['Nova 5T', 'Huawei', 6.26, 3750, 497]

# Check single condition
check_condition(
    product,
    inexpensive,
)

# Check multiple conditions
check_conditions(
    product,
    conditions=(
        inexpensive,
        large_screen,
        apple_product,
    ),
)

# Check multiple products against multiple conditions
matching_products = check_products_conditions(
    products=[product, product, product],
    conditions=(
        inexpensive,
        large_screen,
        apple_product,
    ),
)
```

Comment: This is incredibly useful, but I am attempting to have a singular function which takes in a product such as: ['Nova 5T', 'Huawei', 6.26, 3750, 497] and scans through to see if it reaches a conditions set out. Such as Inexpensive.

Comment: @Tenash Added an edit, maybe that'll clarify a bit.

Comment: okay that simplified it alot. I was initially confused with all the extra stuff but I roughly understand what you were trying to convey. I'll see if I can deconstruct it further to get a better understand. Cheers!

Comment: I appreciate all the help given. I've managed to break down your code into sections that I can understand. I just have a question on how can I implement an operator for != to see if a product is not Apple. Just realised a mistake I made as i did some research on != operators, as there doesn't seem to be a way to implement a operator that can convey !=.

Comment: `operator.ne` is "not equal". I went ahead and edited in the rest of the comparison operators for you too.

Comment: See the correspondence table over at https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was wondering how would you implement multiple products and conditions into this function? I learnt a new thing which is the combinator thanks to you but I am restricted to only product and condition arguments. Can you direct me to a path where I am able to take in multiple products whilst referencing them to multiple conditions?

Comment: @Tenash Sure. That's one more function I just added; it takes a list of products and returns those that match the conditions.